# GLSurfaceView EGL_BAD_ALLOC

Tags: android, opengl-es

My program switches between two `Activities` that each inflate a derived `GLSurfaceView` that uses VBOs.

After switching back and forth between the two Activities a few times, the program crashes and throws the following exception:

```
Java.lang.RuntimeException: createContext failed: EGL_BAD_ALLOC
   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper
      .throwEglException(GLSurfaceView.java:1079)
   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper
      .throwEglException(GLSurfaceView.java:1071)
   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper
      .start(GLSurfaceView.java:927)
   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread
      .guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread
      .run(GLSurfaceView.java:1118)
```

Each time there is a context switch the VBO buffers are deleted, onStop() is called, and a new instance of the next Activity's `GLSurfaceView` is inflated.

I refactored the program to run on only one `GLSurfaceView` and `Activity`, and the program seems to run without incident.

Only polygons and colors are used, no textures.

From doing some internet research, this is a [recognized bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16124).  So how do I do damage control?

EDIT: I SOLVED THE PROBLEM (I FORGOT TO CALL ONPAUSE() / ONRESTART() ON THE VIEWS).

Comment: Why would you be content with 100 FPS, even if the device in question may not support it? No vsync *is* a waste of power, rendering frames that never make it to screen. It sounds like vsync is enabled, which is perfectly fine.

Comment: 59 / 60 are both common :) How do you measure FPS out of interest? It's possible that it's actually 60 but due to your measurement technique it's slightly below and doesn't round up.

Comment: What's the reason for needing 80, precisely?

Comment: Sure :) I'll take a look. By the way, don't base any of your timings on the frame rate, use (lastTimeMS + period) < System.currentTimeMillis(), which will be true when the period has elapsed. Only problem there is when you get multiple periods elapsing in the same timespan :)

Comment: you should make Calendar ca = Calendar.getInstance(); as member of of you surface to get instance one time

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Annoyingly I can't post a comment yet, but I think you mean onResume, not onRestart. Your Activity can be paused without being stopped, which would cause onPause, but not onRestart.

This image (from the [Activity docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)) shows this activity life cycle very nicely:

[image: http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png]

In short, remember to pass onPause and onResume to both your super and to the GLSurfaceView.

From http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/introducing-glsurfaceview.html:

```
public class ClearActivity extends Activity {
    ... snip ...

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mGLView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mGLView.onResume();
    }

    private GLSurfaceView mGLView;
}
```