# How to reproduce "createWindowSurface failed EGL_BAD_ALLOC" exception on my device?

Tags: android

```
ava.lang.RuntimeException: createWindowSurface failed EGL_BAD_ALLOC
       at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.createSurface(HardwareRenderer.java:1387)
       at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.createEglSurface(HardwareRenderer.java:1279)
       at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.initialize(HardwareRenderer.java:1096)
       at android.view.HardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded(HardwareRenderer.java:605)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2596)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2430)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2005)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1076)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5905)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:807)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:601)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:562)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:791)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5633)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:896)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:712)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

I am not using any `OpenGl` or anything of that sort. And hardwareAccelaration is also `false`

Comment: may be this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039107/android-glsurfaceview-egl-bad-alloc

Comment: I am not using any GlSurfaceView . So this will not be the issue

Comment: This is happening only on HTC Desire 820S and no other device